# Is there any way to check for the existence of an SPList or SPListItem without a try/catch block?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In SharePoint, I'd like to be able to check if a particular List or ListItem exists before performing operations on it, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do this without simply catching an ArgumentException. Surely there's a better way?

Comment: Can you give an example of when you wouldn't be sure if a ListItem exists? I can only think of situations where you would retrieve an SPListItem from an SPListItemCollection... and you know it exists then.

Comment: In the case of the SPList, it's basic error handling (a List may be inadvertently deleted, we're preventing the client from shooting themselves in the foot). As for the SPListItem, the process is such that some processing may be done on an item, which can be deleted with good reason, by another user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find an instance of a SPList you could use a linq solution:

```
SPList instance = (from SPList list in web.Lists   
                   where list.RootFolder.Name.Equals(name) 
                   select list).FirstOrDefault();   

if (instance != null)   
{
...// process
```

A similar solution could be made for find an instance of a SPListItem

FirstOrDefault is the trick. Default is null (not an exception).

**UPDATE:**

as a comment, this line of code:

```
from SPList list in web.Lists
```

is the same as writing

```
from list in web.List.Cast<SPList>
```

Comment: web.Lists (an SPListCollection) is not an IEnumerable, so your code above  will not work as is. "from SPList list in web.Lists.Cast<SPList>() where ..." would work though. Could you update your answer to include this, and then I'll mark it as the Accepted Solution?

Thanks!

Comment: My experience is that the code "from SPList list in web.List" is the same as writing "from list in web.List.Cast<SPList>". When you explicitly include the type (SPList) like this a call to Cast<SPList> is made behind the scenes which indeed needs to be made because the SPListCollection does not implement IEnumerable<SPList> as you said. With that said, you shouldn´t include the type if the collection you enumerate indeed implements IEnumerable<T> because then you wouldn´t need or want to call Cast<T>

Comment: Just to confirm then - the line should then read
(from list in web.Lists.Cast<SPList>() where ... )
?

Comment: It doesn´t matter. That line is the same as writing from SPList list in web.Lists. It will translate(compiler stuff probably) to from list in web.Lists.Cast<SPList>....which in turn will translate into a lambdaexpression